# Laravel validate url name

Tags: php, laravel

I need validate url. I need allow only main url sites, example:

```
http://example.com
https://example.com
```

I need prevent this urls:

```
http://example.com/page/blahblahblah
https://example.com/other/bloa
```

How I can validate only host of url and protocol?

Now I use this:

```
'url' => 'required|url',
```

Comment: based on your example counting the number of "/" is all you need

Comment: A regex rule could accomplish what you need, like `'url' => 'required|regex:...'`, but I'm not a regex expert, so I'm not sure what the pattern would look like.

Comment: I agree with @tim, though you can also use `in:url1,url2`.

Comment: Download regexbuddy or generate regex for your required case and append it like this in your validation '"url" => "required|regex:".$regex'

Answer (score 0):

use this methods, then check value for validation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url
...

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but the easiest way may be to create a custom validation rule.

```
php artisan make:rule Maindomain
```

In the passes() method of app/Rules/Maindomain.php, define the rule. In your case, something like:

```
return substr_count($value, '/') == 2;
```

Add a custom error message, if you need one.

Then pass an instance of the rule object like:

```
$request->validate([
   'url' => [new Maindomain],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so I learnt the regular expressions and created the a class to validate the website url. And so far I was able to solve my problem with this.

Here is the link: [How to validate url in laravel using validation rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58705546/how-to-validate-url-in-laravel-using-validation-rule/67726447#67726447)