# How to validate url in laravel using validation rule

Tags: php, laravel

I want  to validate a website address using php validate url function but i dont know how to achieve this. BTW i tried in this way but it doesnot work.

```
$url=filter_var($request->website, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
'website' => 'required|same:,'.$url
```

if someone can help me it would be great.

Comment: You can use  $regex ="/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/gm
";   "url" => "required|regex:".$regex.

Comment: it gives me the following error preg_match(): Unknown modifier '?'

Answer (score 5):

You can use `url` validator by Laravel

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-url

`'website' => 'required|url'`

Or, if you want to build more precise rule, there is a few ways to do it.
There is one of them, the simplest in my opinion:

In your `AppServiceProvider@boot`:

```php
Validator::extend('website', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
  // validation logic, e.g
  return filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
});
```

And then use you rule in validators list:

```php
'website' => ['required', 'website'],
```

Everything explained here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses `filter_var()` with the `FILTER_VALIADTE_URL` option which doesn't allow umlauts. You can write a custom validator or use the regex validation rule in combination with a regular expression.

```
$regex ="/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/";

// specify the rules as array to avoid problems with special characters:  
"website" => array("required", "regex:".$regex)
```

Comment: it gives me the following error
preg_match(): Unknown modifier '?'

Comment: and i cannot create a custom validator

Comment: preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 117

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a bit late to answer, but I learnt to create the regular expressions last night when I came across this same issue and as a matter of fact, this is the very first regular expression that I have created. So far I was able to solve my problem.

Php: 8.0.3
Laravel: 7.x

app/Rules/DomainNameRule.php

```php
class DomainNameRule implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(
        private $caption = 'Website'
    ) {
        $this->caption = $caption;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return preg_match("/^((https?:\/\/)?([w]{3}[\.])?)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{2,}[\.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}([\.][a-zA-Z]{2,6})?$/", $value);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return @implode('<br>', [
            "{$this->caption} - Invalid",
            "- Can start with 'http://www' or 'https://www'",
            "- Must has a domain name (google | microsoft | yahoo | .etc)",
            "- Must end with domain type (.com | .co.in | .online | .etc)",
            "- Special characters allowed: _-",
            "e.g. https://www.google.com | https://www.google.co.in"
        ]);
    }
}
```

```php
use App\Rules\DomainNameRule;

...

'website' => ['required', new DomainNameRule];
```

Here is the link of the youtube video which was quite helpful while I was learning to create the regular expressions: https://youtu.be/zAAXtLo0zuw